# bangla font is not working in pdf-lib custom font

Tags: node.js, express, bangla-font, pdf-lib.js

I have a problem with the Bangla font.

I've got a problem when I embed Bangla font in PDF-LIB. If any fonts are supported then the output didn't show correctly. It shows like a small rectangle.
[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcXM1.png)

And most of time the program is not runned. And terminal say like:

```
regeneratorRuntime is not defined
```

Comment: You need to import a custom bangla font and embed that in pdf-lib. See [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-lib?activeTab=readme#embed-font-and-measure-text).

Comment: I know. And I did this but the problem is the is not running properly. Can you suggest to me any font name that will be run properly?